# vTiger 5.4 How to take values from detailed report into the Bar charts?

Tags: php, charts, report, invoice, vtiger

I have search for hours of how to make this happen but still not succeed. The problem is that i cannot find a way on how to take the value that has been calculated in the detailed report. For example, Invoice Detailed Report with 'monthly' filter with the function SUM for "Total" fields show values  of 1,200. Now, how can i take that 1,200 value and put it in the BarCharts as Y-Axis value so that when mouse hovering the charts, it will show the 1,200? The default BarChart value only show the number of Invoice Detailed Reports Records which means if there are 5 Invoice Detailed Report then the value is 5.

X-axis is the Vertical Line, while Y-Axis is the Horrizontal Line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, the value of the detailed report is the Count of group_by id, thus it can be retrieve at the ReportRun.php